# How Can I read TCL file value by value

Tags: arrays, file, tcl

I have a file in Tcl, and I want to read each value alone as the array... I recognize my file like this

```
PUx(1)  1   2   3   4   5   
PUx(2)  1   2   3   4   5   
PUx(3)  1   2   3   4   5   
PUx(4)  1   2   3   4   5   
PUx(5)  1   2   3   4   5
```

So, I want to get, for example,  the value of PUx(1) one by one and add it to the variable.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mo25X.jpg)

Comment: The exact real file format matters here. Are we dealing with tab-separated values, general double-space separated values, or a fixed-width columns deal?

Comment: Thanks for the answer " Mr.Donal Fellows",  When I print the value inside the file I add  "\t"...but I can remove if it makes problem to read the file as an array.

Comment: Your question is very unclear. Please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

As Donal pointed out, it all depends on the actual format. But if the example data is representative, this might work for you:

```
set content {PUx(1)  1   2   3   4   5   
    PUx(2)  1   2   3   4   5   
    PUx(3)  1   2   3   4   5   
    PUx(4)  1   2   3   4   5   
    PUx(5)  1   2   3   4   5}

foreach line [split $content \n] {
    set values [lassign $line varName]
    set $varName $values
}

parray PUx
```

`lassign` assumes the line-wise data to represent a valid Tcl list. This might or might not be the case for you.

*Update*

You might want to re-organize your dataset, this would allow you to use a Tcl array idiom to access "rows" and "columns" of data in a straightforward manner, more or less:

```
set content {PUx(1,1)  1
    PUx(1,2) 2
    PUx(1,3) 3
    PUx(1,4) 4
    PUx(1,5) 5
    PUx(2,1) 1
    PUx(2,2) 2
    PUx(2,3) 3
    PUx(2,4) 4
    PUx(2,5) 5}

foreach line [split $content \n] {
    set values [lassign $line varName]
    set $varName $values
}

parray PUx

# first column: *,1
foreach {k v} [array get PUx *,1] {
    puts $v
}

# first row: 1,*
foreach {k v} [array get PUx 1,*] {
    puts $v
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer " Mr.Donal Fellows", but in this case, it will read all the value.....this result is already saved in the TCL file, So, I want to read, for example, the value of PUx(1) but not read all value at the same time, just get the first value like 1 and for PUx(2) also the first value...as you read from array.

Comment: @Qusay To access the content of `PUx` element by element (with element being a list), check out Tcl's manual page on [array](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/array.htm). Then, loop over the lists? But maybe I don't get the question, which is vaguely described as @Jerry puts it.

Comment: Thanks, For everyone here, in more depth, I have a file "Xfile"  that save all the value as I explained up. Now,  I  have the equation and I want to add (+)  the first value of PUx(1)= 1 and the first value PUx(2)=1 and other until PUx(5), to be like this Sum=  1+1+1+1+1. Now, the problem, I want to know how to read this value that saved in "Xfile" element by element. not read all at the same time.

Comment: By "Sum= 1+1+1+1+1", you refer to the column-wise sums?

Comment: Thanks "Mr. Mrcalvin" for your answer, I agree with you. We can say I want to read the value as a column...There is any way to read the column in a file in this way.

Comment: Can you influence the format of your "Xfile"? So, can you change it to look like: `PUx(1,1) 1`, `PUx(1,2) 2`, ... `PUx(5,5) 5`. Then, you could read it in as described in my answer and access rows/columns like so: `PUx(1,*)` for the first row, `PUx(*,5)` for the fifth column.

Comment: Thanks "Mr. Mrcalvin", Do you have Idea about the code to do this process.

Comment: Thanks, for everyone here, try to help me.....Ok, I upload a figure about the Xfile that I want to read from it.....you can see I have different column and row let us say I want to add (+) the value PUx(0) until the end...Now, the problem I can not read the value element by element....there is a way for that but to read from the file in this way. https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mo25X.jpg

Comment: I am afraid, I seem to fail to see what the your perceived problem actually is. "reading the value element by element", "add (+) the value PUx(0) until the end". Do you want to compute the sum from a list of numeric values? If this was your main concern, then your question would be ill phrased. See my third attempt of answering then.

Comment: Thanks To everyone here try to help me, "Mr. Mrcalvin", My question " How can I read the value from File That I upload figure for it " i.stack.imgur.com/Mo25X.jpg"  " Element by Element". IF I doing this steps set f [opent Xfile.trc r]  gets $f output puts $output close $f......this code will read all the data at one-time...I want to read it element by element after that I do the process of summation...now the important how to read element by element. My Best Regards

Answer (score 0):

Provided that your main concern is how to compute the sum over a list of elements, these are three options available to:

```
proc lsum1 {x} {
    set r 0
    foreach i $x {
       incr r $i
    }
    return $r
}

proc lsum2 {x} {
    expr [join $x " + "]
}

proc lsum3 {x} {
    ::tcl::mathop::+ {*}$x
}


set x {1 2 3 4 5}
lsum1 $x
lsum2 $x
lsum3 $x
```

`lsum1` and `lsum3` are preferable. `lsum2` is the literate translation of what you describe as your "problem", at least in my reading. You may also want to check the [Tcl wiki](http://wiki.tcl.tk/1354). It gives you some background on the details of `lsum3`.

This can be easily integrated with reading your data, as shown in my first answer:

```
lsum1 $PUx(1)
lsum3 $PUx(1)
```